# find url with regex on text

Tags: php, regex

there are a lot of topics like this one but i don't know what the error i tried a lot
so this is the original text

```
onclick="NewWindow('http://google.com','name','800','600','yes');return false">
```

this is my code

```
    $re1='(onclick)';
  $re2='(=)';
  $re3='(.)';
  $re4='(NewWindow)';
  $re5='(\\()';
  $re6='(.)';
  $re7='((?:http|https)(?::\\/{2}[\\w]+)(?:[\\/|\\.]?)(?:[^\\s"]*))';

  $c=preg_match_all ("/".$re1.$re2.$re3.$re4.$re5.$re6.$re7."/is", $txt, $matches);

  print_r($matches);
```

any one can help me to get the url using regular expression and php??

what is the wrong with this code?

Regards

Comment: You just want to capture the url?

Comment: yes the url only that start with onclick="NewWindow('

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match("/NewWindow\('([^']*)'/",$txt, $matches);
```

matches[1] contains the url

is it what you need ?

(edit: put in code block because a parenthesis was not escaped correclty

Comment: i got an error Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 19. where i should add ) ??

Comment: what ) is missing ? i'm not trying to match the ) of NewWindow()

Comment: ok ok thank you this work on my hosting, it gave that error in wamp server i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
preg_match("/onclick=\"NewWindow\('(.*)','n/",$txt,$matches);
```

Comment: thanks it run ok but it gave back no matches will the previous text affect the process?????

Comment: Could you run this code and tell me if there are any matches?
http://pastebin.com/XvT6VYK2

I'm asking because that exact code is working on my server.

Comment: when i access the your link it say (Access to this site has been blocked as per Court Orders)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, the regex I would use, would be:

```
/(?<=NewWindow\(\').*(http://|https://)[^\'\"]*/i
```

or

```
/(?<=onclick=\"NewWindow\(\').*(http://|https://)[^\'\"]*/i
```

A great tool for testing your regex is: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

It outputs just the url and only does so if it is preceded by "NewWindow('" in the first example or "onclick="NewWindow('", which means, in your case, 'http://google.com').

Comment: error :(     Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '/'

Comment: i think this error Because of wamp server, test it in my hosting it's run but no matches

Comment: Strange, perhaps it had something to do with the escaping... The Regex works, but I have not tested it in a preg_match.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use non-greedy matching for this:

```
preg_match("/onclick=\"NewWindow\('(.*?)'/", $txt, $matches);
```